# How to free the ROM memory allocated to Ubuntu on Virtual Box?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, ram

I installed Ubuntu on Oracle VM Virtual box. I choose 34GB ROM(fixed memory) memory and 4GB RAM memory while installing.

Now I am unable to open Virtual box due to missing *.msi file. So I uninstalled Oracle VM Virtual box.

But memory allocated while installing is not freed. How do I retrieve that memory.

Every time I install windows drive memory will reduce and old memory is never restored back.

How to free memory?

Answer (score 0):

To free the ROM memory(fixed or Flexible) you need to delete the **Ubuntu.vdi** file from your system. This will free the disc space.

After lot of search I found folder where "Ubuntu.vdi" is located.

[Ubuntu.vdi file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIL18.jpg)

I hope on all windows system Ubuntu.vdi file will be located in same location. Just delete the VirtualBox VMs folder before you re install it. It will free up the disc place earlier allocated.